# Is there a way to compare usage of VS Code extensions similar to npmtrends.com?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Often when researching an npm package, I view it on [npmtrends](https://www.npmtrends.com). This gives me a decent idea as to how widely-used the package is. More importantly, it also lists other similar packages and shows a chart comparing their use. [Here's an example comparing Angular/React/Vue](https://www.npmtrends.com/angular-vs-react-vs-vue).

[image]

I'm wondering if a similar tool exists for Visual Studio Code extensions. The Marketplace give download count but doesn't show similar extensions. Is there another tool/site that offers this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update? wondering the same thing

Comment: I haven't yet found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found so far is to use Microsoft's own website. It's not as intuitive as npmtrends, but it does allow you to search and sort by number of installs. For example, looking for "linting javascript":

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=linting%20javascript&target=VSCode&category=Formatters&sortBy=Installs